# ASPX is not loading and rendering in iis 7.0

Tags: git

My solution is running and working fine in IIS6.0. when it comes to IIS 7.0  mypage.aspx is showing blank and it didn`t showing any content, Can any one suggest me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you get any errors?

Comment: Why did you tag this with git?